# Setting Image To Nil Causes ImageView to Disappear in Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have recently moved a bunch of UIImageViews into nested Stack Views (Horizontal and Vertical). Whenever the user presses the play button it animates, then starts a timer. Once the timer reaches 0 it is supposed to flip each card consecutively and hide the image itself. This was working until I added them to a Stack View. I've read that the stack views are buggy when it comes to this sort of thing, but any attempt at fixing it hasn't worked thus far. I'm at an impasse, can anyone point me in the right direction?

#### Issue Occurs In Here I Think

```
//INFO: Disable cards while viewing.
for card in cardsPhone
{
    card.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    flipCard(sender: card)
}



DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {

    for card in self.cardsPhone
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            //THIS IS THE ANIMATION CALL THAT MAKES VIEWS DISAPPEAR.
            self.flipCard(sender: card)

        }
        usleep(20000)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        //INFO: Enable cards after hidden.
        for card in self.cardsPhone
        {
            card.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        //INFO: Enable play button after cards are hidden to prevent crashing layout.
        self.playButtonView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

#### Flip Animation Controller

```
func flipCard(sender: UIImageView)
{
    playButtonView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    //INFO: If there is no UIImage, assign the appropriate image from the array.
    if sender.image == nil
    {
        sender.image = cardsImages[sender.tag]
        UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }
    //INFO: If there is an image, remove it and replace with no Image.
    else
    {
        sender.image = nil
        UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#### Update

I've discovered that if I replace the image on the UIImageView then that is actually what is causing it to disappear. So the issue is related to the code above in the `else` statement where `sender.image = UIImage()`. It doesn't matter if I replace with a different image or not, the moment the image is changed it disappears.

Comment: I think uiview.trasition animation removed your view, please try different animation.

Comment: @RahulPatel no, I can comment that line of code out. It does not remove the view. The line that sets `sender.image = nil` causes it to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read that the stack views are buggy when it comes to this sort of thing

Well, that's not so. They are in fact quite sophisticated and consistent, and their behavior is well defined.

What is a stack view? It's a builder of autolayout constraints. And that is all it is. Putting views inside a stack view means "Please configure these views with equal spacing" (or whatever your setting is for the stack view) "using autolayout constraints that you impose."

Okay, but how does the stack view do that? Autolayout requires four pieces of information, x and y position, and width and height. The stack view will supply the position, but what about the *size* (width and height) of its views? Well, one way to tell it is to give your views internal constraints (if they don't conflict with what else the stack view will do). But in the absence of that, it has to use the *intrinsic size* of its views. And the intrinsic size of an image view under autolayout is the size of the image it contains.

So everything was fine when you had image views with images that were the same size. They all had the same intrinsic size and now the stack view could space them out. But then you took away an image view's image. Now it has *no* image. So it has *no* intrinsic size. So the stack view just removes it from the row (or column or whatever it is).

Your workaround is actually quite a good one, namely, to make sure that the image view always has an image; if it is to look blank, you just give it a blank image. The image looks like the background, but it is still an image with an actual size, and so it gives the image view a size and the image view continues to hold its place.

However another solution would have been simply to give the image view a width constraint the same size as the card image's width.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I've discovered that changing an image on a UIImageView while it's inside of a stack causes it to completely disappear. This is a weird Xcode but but the solution I found was to create a custom background on the fly to get rid of the image and only have the background color. This was done with the following code snippet. It's a bit messy, but it gets the job done.

```
func setColorImage(viewToModify: UIImageView, colorToSet: UIColor)
{
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: viewToModify.layer.bounds.size)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    colorToSet.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    guard (image?.cgImage) != nil else { return }
    viewToModify.image = image
    viewToModify.backgroundColor = colorToSet
    viewToModify.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Essentially this code creates a new cgRect, sets the color, creates a new image from that color, then applies it back to the UIImageView.

Comment: @matt err yes? Did not check to see if it is shrinking, only that it did not appear in the view. I was expecting to be able to remove the image from the imageView and leave the background view. It was that the background view was also disappearing.

Comment: The background layer. The portion that has a color set to it. Forgive my shortcomings, I'm still a student, granted a fairly capable one.

Comment: @matt also, I nearly bought your book. I thought I recognized it from your profile.

Comment: Yes, well, it’s part of the image view. If the image view shrinks to nothing, the background color goes with it. So is that the question, why that happens in a stack view? Because I’m happy to try to explain that if you’re interested. But your solution is a very decent working solution so I won’t add another answer if you don’t want to know any more.

Comment: @matt so suppose I have `var someImage: UIImageView` and I have that setup in the IB. Later I come and change the image to nil `someImage.image = nil` not the view itself rather the image layer. When that happens, it's expected to reduce the size of the UIImageView because the image is gone?

Comment: Yes if you’re using autolayout and nothing else but the contained image gives the image view any size. And a stack view is all about autolayout.

Comment: @matt if you'll post a good description of that I'll happily give you the correct answer for this one. I looked everywhere for it before posing this question and I believe that what you're saying is an invaluable thing to know. I had 3 other "Professional" devs, including a Team Leader look at it and no one could figure it out. I don't think it's widely known what you're talking about.